# Forecasting using Python

Tags: python, forecasting, data-analysis

I have very less training observations (15). I need to predict 6 months into the future. What forecasting model is best suited for this scenario? Here is how my dataset looks

Month        | Response Rate       |% Promoters          |% Detractors        |%Neutrals

2019-01-01     | 5%                 |60%                 |30%                | 10%

2019-02-01

.....

2020-07-01

I need to predict Response Rate, % Promoters, % Detractors and % Neutrals all of which are numeric variables.

I am new to this forum, so pardon me if I have done any mistake while framing the question.

Comment: Sorry I meant 19* observations

Comment: Having just 19 samples are just not enough to apply any machine learning model and predicting target next few months. You can use excel for your analysis for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any forecasting model, then it will do over fitting on your data set, as you have just 19 observations. At least 1000 observations are the good point to start applying any machine learning model.

> I need to predict Response Rate, % Promoters, % Detractors and %
> Neutrals all of which are numeric variables.

You can do data exploration where you start using bar charts, line charts, and try to find the pattern for each of those variables. Using this, if not accurate, but you would be able to understand lump sum forecasted value for upcoming months.

Even built in functions are there in excel. Check this out: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/forecast.html